# Session variables or cookies

Tags: asp.net, session-state, session-cookies

I have a system that enables my Intranet users to process database records. Basically records are ticked/unticked and this updates a running total for each that is placed into separate session variables and then submitted to a different database.  Every so often something odd happens and the values in these session variables can double (or worse) and I've never been able to replicate this (it does seem completely random and luckily rare).

I'm thinking about a possible rewrite and am wondering if it is better to go down the road of using cookies to store values temporarily, and then to force them to expire to clear these values.

As an alternative to these, is ViewState applicable here?  I've read about it briefly but have no experience in explicitly setting viewstate values.

My main concern is that my variables were being affected by someone else using the system at the same time but I thought that part of the point of session variables was that they are only accessible by the session in which they were created?

Comment: Did you read this before : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx** ??

Comment: I admit I only have a cursory understanding of your system, but why are you using a temporary store (session, viewstate, cookies, etc) before updating the actual db?

Comment: Your concern about your variables being affected by other users mostly only applies to [application variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx), which are application-wide. Then there are session variables, which apply for a single session. The viewstate is similar, but only persists for a single page. Viewstate variables can actually be seen in the page source as a serialized value in a hidden field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewState is only used to post back data, it is not a replacement for either because it is not persistent across an entire session. It is a "view" state after all :).

Session variables actually use cookies, but in a more secure manner than simply by storing all pertinent data within them. Just storing values directly in cookies is fine, but users with a bit of simple JavaScript can modify the contents of their cookies. If you're not okay with that, then use sessions.

A small disadvantage of sessions in comparison to storing raw data in cookies is that the data is stored on the server, which does take up space and computing resources. Not much, but it is something to think about if you are going to have a high-traffic site or are thinking about storing everything and the kitchen sink in session.

So how do sessions work? They store data specific to each session user, accessible by a key. That key is usually stored on a cookie on the client's machine. When they access a page, their cookie key is transmitted to the server and relevant data is made accessible. One big thing to remember is that the security of the cookie is the linchpin of the security of the session. If you have a site which is vulnerable to XSS attacks (a subject for a whole other post), a user can steal the cookie of another and masquerade as them, because they will have the id that identifies the other user's session.

So overall, hard to tell you what system to use. Personally I tend to use sessions because they are easy to implement and the added security of not having user-modifiable data is nice. In the end though, you'll have to look at your architecture and decide what is best for you.

Comment: Well I'm basically storing up to 9 values in session, then writing these values to a database, then resetting them before starting over again.  My concern was that I was getting some kind of 'leak' if that makes sense, as sometimes a value of say 30.00 would get written to the db and somewhere along the line it has doubled or even tripled.  I can't see, using session variables, how this could be altered by another user in a different session/machine, so perhaps something is slightly amiss in my code. Thanks for the answer it was very helpful!

Comment: I would imagine that there is something in your code causing problems. Unless you have an XSS attack (which is usually exploited when you allow people to post unescaped HTML to public pages on your site) but if you are just running a small site that is fairly unlikely to happen. Session variables are complex to manage but ASP.NET does all the work for you so if it's not a hack, I would expect it to be a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: I'll go through line by line and see if I can spot any problems. Can I just ask - with my session variables, when they are written to the db I clear them by doing `Session("variablename") = 0`
is this the correct method?

Comment: "Session" has Add() and Remove() methods that you should use for variable manipulation. = 0 would store the value 0 in the variable but not actually remove the entry from the table.

Comment: Yes I noticed I use session.remove in there at various points.  It's a while since I wrote this so I'm familiarising myself with it all again.

Comment: This is rearing it's ugly head again.  Could user1's session variables affect values in user 2's session variables if they have identical names and are both running on the same server?  Or could server lag cause this doubling problem when values were being written to the database?

Comment: The problem is going to more than likely be with your database if you are using one. Session concurrency problems are very unlikely if you follow standard programming procedures.

Comment: I'm using an MSSQL database. What's happening is every so often, an insert statement appears to have been fired twice, so values are effectively doubling. I'm pretty sure it's not related to session as I've never been able to replicate it.

Comment: You are going to have to post this as a new question with more details. I am assuming that your site is not as big as SO which uses ASP.NET... if SO manages with ASP.NET's session architecture, then it would be pretty exceptional if your problem stemmed from it.

Comment: I've got a bit nearer to finding out what is causing the issue.  I have a command e.g. `cmdInsertWE.ExecuteNonQuery()` inside an if...else statement. What's happening is that instead of breaking out of the statement and continuing until the end of the function, it is rerunning the function from the beginning, not resetting my variables hence causing the doubling effect.  It's as if the query is timing out, and the function is being fired again from the start?  Does this sound feasible?

Comment: You are going to have to ask this in a separate question with more details + code. Could be, but can't say with the info you have given.